# Use google drive to store android app data

Tags: java, android, google-sheets

I'm working on a messaging app based on the position,users can anonimously write message in the app and if an user is near the one who wrote the message he will be able to see the message on the app (I know this already exists but I'm making mine).
Anyway the problem is when i need to save and load users messages and positions,i would like to use google drive (or eventually dropbox) to host data,I want to store them on my google drive and not in the user GD.
I thought about creating a google spreadsheet like this:

```
Message        Position
"Hi everyone"  123912,123184
"Hola"         123912,123184
"Hi"           123912,123184
```

and then get the data every x seconds and when someone write something i'll update the sheet with the new row,I searched for this but I only find tutorial about managing the user's GD.
Am I using the wrong approach?

Comment: This may backfire you in the future. I see three problems: **1)** If you get really famous, drive or dropbox is **not** an option. You'll run out of space in a matter of minutes, maybe. **2)** Keeping the current user position (even if they're anonymous) in an insecure store like drive (basically anyone taking your phone would be able to get this) might not be well received. **3)** If you happen to get not even many users, but many messages, doing proximity searches in a spreadsheet may become slow and a madness. I'd recommend looking for database alternatives (there are cheap MBaaS out there)

Comment: @Korcholis Thanks for the advice,for now I would just try to work with a server,I won't probably upload the app so it's just a test

Comment: Good to know then. Just saying, in case you wanted to release it. I won't bother with this thread, good luck with your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if ur solution of using GDrive is the good one but just in case:

- You can use the Google Drive REST api to do what you want with drive file.

here's some help https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android